# HTML Dom Direct property change Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Im trying to learn Dom and still in the experimental stages.

Question:
why can i change the text content but it does not render to the page?

```js
let nestedul = document.querySelector("main ul#nestedlistparent");

console.log(nestedul);

/* THIS IS WORKING */
let h1 = nestedul.querySelector("h1");
h1.innerText = "somethingchanged".toUpperCase();

/*THIS IS NOT WORKING*/
console.log(nestedul.querySelector("h1").innerText.toUpperCase());
```

```html
<main>                 
    <ul id="nestedlistparent">
        <h1 id="header-nestedlistchild">nestedlistchild</h1>
        <ul id="nestedlistchild">
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>


    </ul>
</main>
```

The end Result is that the h1 element does not render the changes. But it shows in console.log.
[image]

Comment: What is not working here?

Comment: the nestedul.querySelector("h1").innerText.toUpperCase();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until and unless you don't assign the value you are not really changing DOM content, going the shortcut way is for sure converting the text to Upper case, but nowhere the value is getting assigned to.

For example:

`console.log(4 + 7)` is going to log `11` on the console but is not getting assigned anywhere so you won't be able to see the change, while in a case like `let a = 0` then `a = 4 + 7`, here I am assigning the result to the variable and that is getting stored in it, so we can expect a change in the value of `a`, similarly goes for the DOM Node in your case.

Hope this clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Forget about the console.log. I wrote it extra, that i can test the Uppercase method, if it was working.

What do you mean by assigning it? 
Can you give me an example?

Comment: I didn't get you, can you explain it a bit more clearly what exactly the problem is, if required you can edit the question too, to make it more clear.

Comment: what im trying to do is to change the textcontent/value of the H1 element/tag.

so if im correct the nestedul.querySelector("h1") is a document object with the reference of the h1 tag. So that i can have access to its attributes. By using the innterText attribute. I have acces to its text value which is a string. With a string value i can use the method toUpperCase() which returns the string value to Uppercases.

by Using the console.log() i have proof that the value has change to Uppercase. But the changes was not shown in the page.

Comment: what im Thinking is:

MANUALLY
'let word = nestedul.querySelector("h1").innerText;'
'word = nestedlistchild.toUpperCase();'

AUTOMATIC
what i did is like a short cut.
nestedul.querySelector("h1").innerText.toUpperCase();